# How to access custom static page in VueJS CLI 3 generated app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I have created a default Vue CLI 3 project (with vue-router) but beside webapp I'd also like to have few static pages (eg. about, faq, terms etc...) that do not require vue framework or any special javascript logic.

So I've added `faq.html` in `/public` folder and I tried to access it via `https://localhost:8080/faq` but I always get index.html page where vue is taking over and loading my app.

How can I have static html pages in public folder not to be handled by vue-router and instead just delivered to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should use History mode.
I think you run it on Windows, if you want to access the router from Pullic you must use History mode, 
so your router will look like this

`/index.html#/faq`

if you run it on your server. the router will works fine without history mode

```
  const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```